# Composite Primary key verses one column based primary key

Tags: database-design

I have gone through
[Database Design: Composite key vs one column primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264248/database-design-composite-key-vs-one-column-primary-key)

For a table which can never be referenced as foreign key by any other table, what are the pros and cons in term of insert and update of having a single-column/simple primary key verses a multi-column/composite primary key?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, a multi-column primary key is still a bad choice, if:

- your primary key is also the clustering key
- your table also contains other non-clustered indices

Because:

- the value(s) from the clustering key (e.g. the single INT column, or your composite key) will be added to each and every entry in each and every non-clustered index

Thus: if you have a composite primary key of 200 bytes in size, and you have a few non-clustered indices on your table, you'd be wasting **a lot** of memory on your SQL Server - and not just on the (comparatively cheap) disks, but also in SQL Server main memory (which typically isn't quite as cheap).

Besides waste of space, your performance will also lag, since larger indices mean more disk I/O for the same operations.

In general: use a composite primary key on your table **only** if you never need to reference that table (really never, not even in the future), and if you have **no other** non-clustered indices on that table.

Comment: You've given some reasons why not to have an over-large clustered index in SQL Server. These problems are unrelated to primary keys however. A clustered index and a key are not the same thing - even in SQL Server. Also a composite key could well be smaller than a single attribute key - so size alone is not an argument for avoiding composite keys.

Comment: @dportas: strictly speaking, you're right. But at least 90% of primary keys in SQL server are also clustering key - mostly because many devs just simply don't know anything about clustering keys and their primary keys become their clustering keys automatically.

Comment: I have a table whose primary (clustered) key is UserID and Timestamp for a log table.  I figured this is fine, because it's the *only* index/key on the table.  It can produce sums for a single user quickly because UserID is the *first* column in that clustered index (primary key), and including the time stamp in the index ensures it's unique.  Does that sound good?

Comment: @Triynko: depends on the datatypes of those two columns, and their characteristics: can they change? Are the NOT NULL and unique?

Comment: UserID is a bigint, and Timestamp is datetime2(7), so they are non-null, fixed-length, and never change.  We used to use "Username" as a primary key when the system was very young, but we needed to be able to change it, so rather than adding cascade updates to this variable-length key, I made it more efficient by creating just a fixed-length integer UserID that never changes, and is only used for relationships between database tables as a PK/FK.

Answer (score 2):

And how can you possibly be absolutely certain your key "could never be referenced by a FK" ?

Your combination of attributes is indeed unique (otherwise you wouldn't be considering making it a 'primary key').

Your combination of attributes is therefore a valid means of identification for the real-world thing that is described in your table.

Saying that this could never be referenced by a FK is tantamount to saying that "no extra information regarding this type of thing will ever become relevant to the business".  How can you possibly know ?

Comment: Dear, thanks for prompt reply, but i am still abide by my statement of "never be referenced by a FK" because particular table is lowest in hirarchy of tables in my database. if u would require then i would give u exact example in my case.

Comment: It's very easy to design it to never be referenced by a FK, because by design certain kinds of information are self-contained and final.  For example, a log table with a composite clustered primary key of UserID,Timestamp is unique and is clustered with UserID first so individual user logs can be retrieved quickly with minimal I/O.  The reason no other table would ever need to reference such a log entry/key, is because it's self-contained by design.  In other words, there is no new/external/additional information that would ever need to refer to or be added to that row in a separate table.

Answer (score 1):

Business requirements (data integrity requirements) should be the determining factor about what keys to implement. Enforcing uniqueness on one attribute is obviously a different to enforcing it on more than one because duplicates that would be permitted in one case would not be permitted in the other (unless you implement *both* keys of course).

Note that marc's answer applies only to clustered indexes, not primary keys. They are not the same thing. His answer is also specific to SQL Server.

Comment: Yes, my answer is SQL Server specific, and yes, it applies to clustering keys - but by default, your SQL Server primary keys **ARE** clustering keys - unless you explicitly turn that off - might the vast majority of devs won't do.....

Comment: Dear ALL,
i am confused from all above replies.

If in my case composite key is primary key and it would also have clustered indexes & this table would never use as FK & there is no other non clustered index then wat would be impact insertion and updation in this table.

It is pertinent to mention here that this table would have huge amount of data.

Comment: @ibrar: Yes of course there is an impact. The purpose of such a constraint is precisely to prevent incorrect updates or inserts. Obviously there is an overhead in performing this check but if you didn't want to check for uniqueness then you wouldn't implement the constraint at all. Whether to implement it on single or multiple columns is therefore not a performance related question - it depends on what you want achieve. I'm not aware of any general difference in performance between single or multiple columns in indexes but it may depend on many things so I suggest you test it out for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

There are two competing philosophies on this issue.

I'm firmly in the camp of using composite primary keys for certain tables, myself.

When I design a database, I use ER modeling to collect information requirements in one place.  Every value to be served up by the database is an instance of an attribute, and every attribute describes a subject matter entity or a relationship among two or more subject matter entites.  Foreign keys don't go into the analysis phase.

Before starting database design, I decide how each entity will be identified, from the application perspective.  These are going to give me my primary keys.  Every table that describes an entity will have a simple primary key, the identifier for the entity.   Simple relationships (binary, many-to-one) don't need a table of their own.  Every table that describes a complex relationship will have a composite primary key made up of the primary keys of the participating entities.

Foreign keys plug in in the obvious way.  Well, obvious to me, at least. This provides an initial table design in 3NF, and maybe higher.  Table design might be altered by further normalization or by other design patterns incompatible with normalization  (so called denormalization).  But this is the first cut at table design.

This design practice results in different results as far as performance and data integrity than the prevailing practice.  The prevaling practice  puts an autonumber column called "id" in as the first column of every table.  This column becomes the primary key.

In essence, this practice uses the SQL table structure to mimic the graph model of data, even if it looks like a relational model.  The id column is essentially a surrogate for the row's address.  The graph model of data has an upside and a downside.  More on this if requested.