# How to drop a primary key? I get incorrect table definition

Tags: mysql, sql, primary-key

I am trying to run this query:

```
ALTER TABLE table DROP PRIMARY KEY, ADD PRIMARY KEY( `CUSTNO` , `DEPTNO` , `PRODNO` , `DT` );
```

I get

```
Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to alter your pk column so that it hasn't auto_increment modifier anymore.

Comment: @Anzeo: no, he doesn't. he just removes the primary-key-index.

Comment: @oezi, yup noticed I was incorrect, didn't noticed you already replied on my comment

Answer (score 1):

you'll have to do this in 3 (or 4) steps:

1. remove the "auto-incremet" attribute from your current primary key
2. drop your primary key
3. set the new primary key
4. (reset "auto_incremet" to your orl primary-key-column)

**EDIT:** maybe setting a new primary isn't what you realy want to do. please take a look at [unique indexes](http://www.google.de/#sclient=psy&hl=de&safe=off&q=unique+index+mysql&aq=2&aqi=g5&aql=&oq=unique+index&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=bbf54a1b171bfb46) - i think thats waht you want to set on your other columns to make sure they don't occur more than once.

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, if I'm correct you're defining a compound key? This is usually bad practice. It's better to have an extra ID column and to add a separate constraint to check you have a unique combination. And as codymanix suggested, you need to first alter the column to not have auto_increment anymore and then drop it.

Comment: to "This is usually bad practice": uhm... no? what about linking-tables for n-m relationships (just as one example)?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264248/database-design-composite-key-vs-one-column-primary-key/1264256#1264256 for an argumentation